# Match an option in select form with boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following piece of code

```
%br
= f.label :active, 'Status'
= f.select :active, ['Active','Inactive']
```

Symbol :active is a boolean type var. How can i match Active => 1/True, and Inactive => 0/False , for the database adding.

Sorry for the newbie question, but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can provide a pair of values for each options: first will be used as label (inner text of `<option>` tag), second will be used as a `value` attribute:

```
= f.select :active, [['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]]
```

It'll render something like:

```
<select name="model[active]">
  <option value="true">Active</option>
  <option value="false">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Have a look at the docs for [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) and [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).

Answer (score 4):

A small extension of the earlier answer, if you're using a dropdown.

I needed to use "options_for_select." Also, ":selected" stores the value for the next time you return to the form.

```
<%= f.select(:active, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]], {:selected => @symbol.active}),:prompt => "Select") %>
```