# Want Select box to output yes and no instead of true and false ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to ruby on rails, have small question, in my application I want select box to output Yes or No in the browser instead of "true" or "false".

I'm not sure the best way to do this. I would highly appreciate if some one help me to sort out...and here is the codes which i used in the form:

```
 <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :sample %>
        <%= f.select :sample, [["Yes", true], ["No", false]], :include_blank => true %>
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match an option in select form with boolean values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430969/match-an-option-in-select-form-with-boolean-values)

Comment: Is your code working?

Comment: The code in your question looks like the answer. So, what's the question?

Comment: yeah the code works well, it is only displaying true and false in the browser, which i don't want, i want only YES and NO to be displayed in the browser

Comment: By the way that is also not rendering as above given links by David <select name="model[active]">
  <option value="true">Active</option>
  <option value="false">Inactive</option>
</select>

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Then I found this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102835/3375663). The simplest way is to create a function in the application helper that takes in a boolean and display as Yes/No.

For instance; I've a Todo app if user have completed the Task they can select a check box. so,

`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def complete_checkbox(boolean)
    boolean ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end
```

in your view page

```
<%=complete_checkbox(task.complete?)%>
```